# Durandal, rebinding views and bootstrap widgets

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, durandal

I have a view with a bootstrap accordion. Navigating to the view, away from the view, and back to the view disables the accordion functionality.

I imagine the problem is that once the HTML is rendered, it isn't fully disposed of on navigate away?

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

My fault.

I had made two naming mistakes. First, instead of changing the IDs of the two accordions, I changed the classes. Whoops. Second, two of the tabs IDs overlapped. This allowed the first one to work, the second one to override it, and the first one to break in the process.

The view composition handles this case well.